# How to increase MaxStringContentLength on the server side for binary Http binding

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, wcf-binding, maxstringcontentlength

I recently converted some Silverlight 3 WCF services to use the new binary http bindings.  Long strings are often sent over to the server for deserialization in these services and I previously used  to ensure the data could be read properly.  However, with the new binding I can't find the correct place to add the  element:

```
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="binaryHttpBinding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxSessionSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647"/>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Here's one attempt:

```
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="binaryHttpBinding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxSessionSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647"/>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
          <textMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880"
            maxArrayLength="200000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

That caused other problems - it doesn't seem like a good idea to have a binary encoding and a textMessageEncoding in the same binding.  So using only the binary encoding, how can I increase the reader quotas to allow deserialization of large strings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the solution I found:

```
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="binaryHttpBinding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxSessionSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880"
            maxArrayLength="200000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```